# How to make a browser back button skip inner page navigation and go back to a previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, history, back

We're using multiple tabs on some of the pages in our MVC web app, and after going through a few them and then clicking the back button, the URLs change accordingly, but you have to click through all of them until you get to the previous page.

What I'd like to do, is go back to that previous page any time I click the browser's back button, so basically skip all the URLs containing '#'. For example if I got to `page2#tab3` like:
`page1 -> page2#tab1 -> page2#tab2 -> page2#tab3`, I'd like to `page2#tab3 -> page1` upon clicking the back button.

Also we do have our custom navigation buttons already, but we'd also like to implement this.

Comment: *the URLs change accordingly* - are you using `pushState`?  Change to `replaceState`

Comment: @freedomn-m it sounds more like they are using a simple <a href="#foo">

Comment: @Kaiido quite possibly, but then why call it "inner page navigation"?   Clearly needs more info from OP.

Comment: Because hash navigation is "inner page navigation"?

Comment: If you're talking about the browser back button, you can't customize its behavior. You need to manipulate the history like @freedomn-m mentions. It would be better UX-wise if you add a link somewhere that clearly indicates that the user will be redirected to page1 from page2#tab3.

Comment: yea sorry if I wasn't clear with "Inner page navigation", it's hash navigation. 

@CoodleNoodle we do have links/buttons that do that, but I've been given a task to see if there's a way to do what I've described in a question with the browser back button too

Comment: Please check my answer ,it should help

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `onhashchange` listener to meet your custom need. Please check
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Also you can modify HistoryAPI as per your needs. Please check
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: thanks, I found out about `onhashchange` in the meantime too, but now I have a problem of detecting user clicking the back button. I've tried with PerformanceNavigationTiming, but it's not working as expected, at least not in Chrome. Instead of type being 'back-forward', it's always 'navigate' for some reason. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it helps you in moving forward. Logic should be to check the presence of # in url in this listener and then replace that item in history with first url without hash.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote. :( Also my problem is still unsolved and it's been put on hold, I have other more urgent tasks to finish right now. Thanks anyway, I would definitely upvote your answer if I could.

Answer (score -2):

in react you can do it with useHistory hook. But I don't know how to implement it in a normal JS project.

Comment: This isn't really helpful, is it? The OP doesn't mention anything regarding React.